# Trend line of a plot, based on variable values

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to draw a trend line of a plot. The only way I found is by using tables:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks, mark = *] table {\datatable};
\addplot [red] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

So I had to define a table. Here's the issue. My values for the plot are variables. I defined those that way (example with x1): `\newcommand{\xOne}{32}`

So my table should be :

```
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y
\xOne{} \yOne
\xTwo{} \yTwo
\xThree{} \yThree
}\datatable
```

But it doesnt work since it appears that it doesnt recognize those as numbers.
I want my values to stay variables since I'm using those eveywhere in my report : I want to be able to change it quickly just by changing the value in the command.

Is it possible to create that type of table using variables ?

(Sorry for my average english, I may not use all terms correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use comma as a column separator, and not have the brace pair after the macro name in the first column, then it works fine:

```
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
X,Y
\xOne,\yOne
\xTwo,\yTwo
\xThree,\yThree
}\datatable
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\xOne}{32}
\newcommand{\yOne}{32}
\newcommand{\xTwo}{34}
\newcommand{\yTwo}{33}
\newcommand{\xThree}{37}
\newcommand{\yThree}{35}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
X,Y
\xOne,\yOne
\xTwo,\yTwo
\xThree,\yThree
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [only marks, mark = *] table {\datatable};
\addplot [red] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] \datatable;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```